# Options for printing white or near white? (Examples included)

Tags: white, ink

So, I'm trying to find a solution for printing white ink or nearly white ink on top of scrapbook paper.

My wife really enjoys a shop on ETSY, but wants to do some DIY projects and with her birthday coming up I was trying to find a solution for this.  We have a 13" printer that is a Canon Ix6820 and initially I thought, no problem, we can print the 12"x 12" scrapbook paper in there, until I got to the obvious problem of white...

Here's a link of a product that is sold and she's looking to do something similar where it, to me, appears they're printing white ink on a background like scrapbook paper.

https://www.etsy.com/listing/527415881/father-of-the-bride-gift-mother-of-the?ref=hp_rv

I'd love some help if anyone has suggestions, comments etc.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/663316/can-a-printer-print-white-color You may want to try embossing.

Answer (score 1):

You can print white all you need is a new ink cartridge*. Unfortunately none are easily available for the canon you have. Its easier to find white ink for Epson printers though. And any commercial provider should have no problems. You may want to talk with a ink shop that specializes in refilling cartridges, though to be honest it is easier to get it printed elsewhere.

* Note that white ink opaque and does not mix well with other colors as it has to be laid down first. Thus, the pigment in white is different which means it may not be compatible with the printer driver and or the printing technology used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like poor man screen printing? Like here - http://craftgrrl.livejournal.com/3674467.html

I changed the "recipe" a little bit as I print negative on the nylon. Then I fix the print with fixture (hair spray is enough). It's good to use 3 or 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to print on plain white paper with a coloured background image instead. If you do that, then no white ink needs to be used.

All you need is an image of the wood planks, then use an image editor like Photoshop or GIMP (which is free) to type white text. Then print it on plain white paper.

Answer (score 0):

The best result would be to get a high res image of the background she wants, (i.e blackboard or wood texture) and do an overlay of the white type in a photo manipulation program like photoshop. If she makes the text (layer)  transparent (and adjusts the degree of transparency) you can get a really effective chalk look. She could even do some distressing of the type with the brushes.If your printer is high res you should get a great result, try using semi gloss photo paper.